# Fastest way to search dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, search

I am looking for the most efficient way to search a large dataframe based on specific conditions. I have tried .loc, .iloc, and numpy, but all of them are too slow. The fastest thus far is with numpy, where my code looks something like this:

```
ParsedTimestamp = []

for index, row in df_primary.iterrows():

    d_index = list(np.where((df_data['filePath'] == row['FilePath']) & (df_data['session id'] == row['ChannelName']) & (df_data['message'] == row['Text']) & (df_data['d_temp'] == row['MessageTimestamp']))[0])[0]  

    ParsedTimestamp.append(df_data.loc[d_index]['Datetime UTC'])
```

As you may be able to tell, I have one datadrame (df_primary) that I need to match 4 values from another dataframe (df_data) to find a more accurate timestamp. The issue is that each search for the index in df_data that matches the row in df_primary takes over 1 second, which is much too long. The df_data dataframe is about 2.5 million rows.

I am open to converting the dataframes to dictionaries or any other forms, but from my research I have been told that dictionaries are less efficient at this size. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just merge?

```
ParsedTimestamp = pd.merge(
    df_data, df_primary,
    left_on=['filePath','session id','message','MessageTimestamp','d_temp'],
    right_on=['FilePath','ChannelName','Text','MessageTimestamp']
)['Datetime UTC']
```